# Fetch data containing a variable

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

My goal is to get the `uuid` from a Minecraft username via the Mojang API and then run it through the Hypixel Skyblock API. My problem is that I can't use the variable `${jsonsbid.id}` inside `JSON.stringify`. I'm quite new to coding and I can't seem to get it working.

I'm using the Discord.js API to send out the JSON result as message.

```js
import { key } from './config.json';

client.on('message', message => {
  const prefix = '!skyblock ';
  const skyblock = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
  const fetch = require('node-fetch');
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return; {
    try {
      fetch(`https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/${skyblock}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(jsonsbid => fetch(`https://api.hypixel.net/Skyblock/profiles?uuid=${jsonsbid.id}&key=${key}`))
        .then(responsesb => responsesb.json())
        .then(jsonsb => message.channel.send(`Coins: ${JSON.stringify(jsonsb.profiles[0].members.${jsonsbid.id}.coins_purse)}`)) //this is the line i need to get working
    } catch (err) {
      message.channel.send('A error occured')
    }
  };
```

Well I hope you can help me so I can learn more about coding and js.

Comment: The `jsonsbid` param is the JSON response from Mojang, it is enclosed within the 2nd `.then`. You will not be able to use it, unless you set it as a variable.

Comment: how do i set it as variable in this case? Sorry im really new to json and im trying out at the moment. But even then it throws me out errors if i want to define it within the JSON.stringify

Answer (score 0):

You could create a cache called `jsonsbidCache` in your bot that stores the `jsonsbid` JSON result by the key `skyblock`. You can then later access it in the final `.then` call.

If you only need to reference `jsonsbid.id`, then you could modify this to only cache said `id` value.

```js
import { key } from './config.json';

const mojangApiUrl = 'https://api.mojang.com';
const skyblockApiUrl = 'https://api.hypixel.net/Skyblock';

const displayCoins = (member) => {
  return `Coins: ${JSON.stringify(member.coins_purse)}`;
};

const jsonsbidCache = new Map(); // Cache

client.on('message', message => {
  const prefix = '!skyblock ';
  const skyblock = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
  const fetch = require('node-fetch');
  
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) {
    return;
  }
  
  try {
    fetch(`${mojangApiUrl}/users/profiles/minecraft/${skyblock}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(jsonsbid => {
        jsonsbidCache.set(skyblock, jsonsbid); // Cache it
        return fetch(`${skyblockApiUrl}/profiles?uuid=${jsonsbid.id}&key=${key}`)
      })
      .then(responsesb => responsesb.json())
      .then(jsonsb => {
        const memberId = jsonsbidCache.get(skyblock).id;
        const member = jsonsb.profiles[0].members[memberId];
        message.channel.send(displayCoins(member))
      })
  } catch (err) {
    message.channel.send('A error occured');
  }
}
```

Comment: It returns the error: "Syntax Error: missing ) after argument list". This is the exact error why i wrote this thread and it says it is missing directly after the members.$

Comment: @AroPixツSorry, I was updating it, check it again. I modified it to be clearer. Sometimes chaining single-line lambda expressions can make it hard to tell what is going on.

Comment: thx for the help because i guess im so much closer now but it returns me Coins: undefined. But i think thats a thing that i can fix myself.

Comment: @AroPixツJust make sure that when you are looking-up the value in the cache, that the JSON is not `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: the json cache returns the mojang uuid but i cant seem to find the mistake why the json lookup returns undefined on the side of hypixel because it should normally work

Comment: @AroPixツ I obfuscated your key, make sure the URL contains the appropriate key. Your keys should be in a config file e.g. `config.json` at the root of your application or somewhere on the host machine. They should never be in the code, especially if you are hosting the source code somewhere.

Comment: i have actually made a const for the key just to test if it is the problem and it isnt.

Comment: @AroPixツ Well, if you cannot get the JSON from Skyblock then that is another issue.

Comment: Well it is actually a mistake in your code. Because if i only try to access the const member then it throws me out a error that tells me that it isnt possible to send a empty message. But if i use the json field cute_name by the skyblock api it is working properly.

Comment: i just found out that in the code it is profiles[0].members[memberId] but the uuid has a own field so i tried it with .[memberId] but it tells me that [ is a unexpted token and if i use it without the [] then it visual studio code shows me that it isnt read by any line in the file.

Comment: @AroPixツ you need the square braces because you are accessing a property by a dynamic value. You do not place a dot before an opening bracket.